# JMeter: database clob in variable

Tags: oracle, jmeter

I have JDBC sample which selects oracle clob inside a variable. However, I need to use the content of this variable in the HTTP request, but the variable expansion doesn't evaluate to clob's content, but it's name instead. If I try to cast the clob to_char in the SQL query, I get an error buffer size is too small. How to correctly convert clob to string in jmeter?

Answer (score 3):

1. For example you have a table with a [CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#SQLRF20042) field which looks like:

   ```
   SQL> select * from sometable;

   SOMEDATA
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   hello
   ```
2. Which is returned to JMeter as something non-readable:

   [image: JMeter Oracle Clob]
3. Declare a "Result Variable Name" with a meaningful reference name, i.e. `clob`

   [image: JMeter Oracle Result Variable]
4. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the JDBC Request sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def data = vars.getObject('clob').get(0).get('SOMEDATA')?.characterStream?.text
   log.info('Value from CLOB field: ' + data)
   ```

   The above code will extract the value from the CLOB field and print it into *jmeter.log* file

   [image: JMeter Oracle CLOB field]

The answer is inspired by the [Performance Testing BLOB from a MySQL Database with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-blob-from-a-mysql-database-with-jmeter) article.

Comment: what libraries do you have or plugins? I'm getting the following error

Comment: 021-12-14 18:04:22,488 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: characterStream for class: oracle.sql.BLOB
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]

Comment: The original question from 2018 is about [CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html) and you're trying to read data from [BLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefblob.html), in BLOB you have the [binaryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oralob.htm#i1055962). Alternatively you can use something like `vars.getObject("Blob").get(0).get("TEXT");` as in the [referenced article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-blob-from-a-mysql-database-with-jmeter) (who reads references in 2021?)